# Why does this question say it was edited, but there's no sign that it was?

Tags: support, editing

Looking at https://aviation.stackexchange.com, there's a [question asked by me six years ago](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20847/in-an-emergency-how-much-runway-does-an-a320-need-to-stop-safely) showing that it had an edit applied 2 days ago by user [Hartley](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/63486/hartley).

When I saw this, I was curious to see what the edit was. I couldn't see anything by just scanning the question, so I tried pressing the EDIT link on the question; when I do that, the dropdown at the top of that page shows one edit from six years ago. So why does the question show 'last activity' 2 days ago?

Comment: Hiya! Each site has its own meta and this is the meta for Aviation. :) In future, please ask questions about specific sites on their specific meta. You can find it by clicking on the hamburger menu in the upper right corner and picking [sitename] Meta. If you have a question about the entire network or a few sites on the network, it can go on [meta.se] instead. :)

Comment: Are you certain that the change made was an edit and not a new answer? I see an answer from two days ago from that user - that's now been deleted - but I don't see an edit.

Comment: Catija - thanks, I'm sure that must be the reason (answer supplied then deleted). I can't see that (the deleted question) but I guess that's something moderators can see and not others. Thank you for satisfying my curiosity ... and thanks for explaining about the site specific meta.

Comment: @glaucon I'm curious what you see on your question's [timeline](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/20847/timeline). To me it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kXzH.png) showing the deleted answer actions, but they might also be hidden for users with less than 10K rep.

Comment: @Bianfable : When I look at the link I see what's shown on your screen shot except the pink panels (which show deleted questions). As you say I presume it's to do with my rep. Not terribly worried about all this, I was just unaware that creating and deleting a question would be reflected in the "modified x days ago" stuff. By the way I had also forgotten how to access the timeline which you linked to so that was useful to know although, as mentioned, in this case it wouldn't have thrown any light on my question due to my rep.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is

> Hartley 1 modified 2 days ago

Which is a little misleading and could seem like that user edited the question, but in fact they [posted an answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/93153/100). This answer was subsequently deleted, which only [10K rep users](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can view.